# Changing metric for dhcpcd

Tags: networking

I am trying to build a fallback connection for my ubuntu box on eth1 (it is actually a Huawei HiLink mobile broadband modem). This is the content of my interfaces file:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet manual

auto eth1
allow-hotplug eth1
iface eth1 inet manual
    metric 400            # does not work
```

I am using dhcpcd as networkmanager. I have read that dhcpcd automatically sets the metric of ethernet devices to 200+ and of wlan devices to 300+. Here is my output of `route -n`:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.42.0.1       0.0.0.0         UG    202    0        0 eth0
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    203    0        0 eth1
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    304    0        0 wlan0
10.42.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     202    0        0 eth0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     304    0        0 wlan0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     203    0        0 eth1
```

Is it possible to change metric in dhcpcd elsewhere? Because in the interfaces file it simply does not work!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The configuration file for dhcpcd is /etc/dhcpcd.conf.
I just had to add these two lines:

```
interface eth1
metric 400
```